# LocalStorage for React Login Screen with reCaptcha

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, recaptcha

Hello everyone i try to use localStorage when user try to login my website if he/she try more than 2 times reCaptcha appear only way is click checkbox in reCaptcha but if user refresh the page reCaptcha is gone because of my state attempNumber.  I want to keep attempNumber in localStorage and use firstly localStorage if user try more than 2 , when refresh page , reCaptche should be there .

I tried like that, but it is not working.If you help me i will be so appreciate for that . Thank you everyone .

```
 this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      load: false,
      attempCount: 0,
    };

 handleLogin(e) {
    const {
      email, password, recaptcha,
    } = this.state;

    const cachedHits = localStorage.getItem(this.state.attempCount);

    if (cachedHits) {
      this.setState({ attempCount: JSON.parse(cachedHits) });
      return;
    }
    this.setState({ attempCount: this.state.attempCount + 1 });
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.props.doSignIn({ email, password, recaptcha });
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, code you have added doesn't show how and where you are setting value in localStorage.

I assume you will update `localstorage` in login button click event something like this

```
localStorage.setItem('clickCount', this.state.attempCount );
```

assuming your `this.state.attempCount` is incremented by 1 on click

Now to get its value use

```
let count = localStorage.getItem('clickCount');

if(count > 2){
  // show Captcha
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your doSignIn code it is hard to tell what is happening with your localStorage, but your call to localStorage in the code you pasted is passing your attemptCount as the key. You should use a string as the key such as 'attemptCount' rather than a key that will change with your state changes.

That might not be all your problem, but is what I noticed so far.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to get the value under key `0` if you take a look at the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem). Try to save it under a key you now as  `localStorage.setItem('attempts', this.state.attempCount)` and then `localStorage.getItem('attempts')`.

When you do a `getItem` I believe it will return a `string`, so do a parse `parseInt(localStorage.getItem('attempts'), 10)` before using it for any operation.

There are two issues with the code:

1. value is never beign set in localstorage.
2. First time when handleLogin is called, below line
   const cachedHits = localStorage.getItem(0);
   it tries to fetch value for zero which is never stored in local storage and it returns null(i.e cachedHits= null),
   then it skips the if part and sets attempCount in state to 1 and show captcha.
   next time when handleLogin is called, 
   const cachedHits = localStorage.getItem(1); which is again not present in cache and cachedHits= null and so on...
   so, you need to set value in localStorage against some key like and in getItem use that key